# RabbitMQ throughput falls off when a second process consumers from a queue

Tags: java, spring, performance, rabbitmq

So, detailed description. I'm working on a microservice framework that uses Rabbit as the event bus. Each service runs on it's own dedicated VM inside a Tomcat container (4 cores, 4GB RAM of which 2 are available to Tomcat).

Each service both consumes and publishes messages back to Rabbit. When I crank up the consumers, channel settings and prefetch size I can get an individual service to perform well. My problem comes when I try to test scalability, i.e. a 2nd VM instance with the service running on it.

Instead of the throughput doubling (or at least increasing), it can actually get slower, and I'm very confused. I've checked for errors and exceptions in the service, used analytics tools (AppDynamics) to check the time spent in the service and the resources used, and everything looks fine, so as far as I can tell it's my Rabbit configuration that's the problem.

The specific settings used to achieve high performance for one service are:
-Consumers: 20.
-Channel cache size: 200
-Prefetch: 500

Using this it seems to work quite well. However when I add the second service the queues aren't being consumed as fast and they start to back up quite quickly, and I'm at a loss to understand why.

I've experimented a little with the settings above but can't seem to get anywhere.

I don't have any access to the Rabbit cluster to change settings so I can't do anything there, but I have full control over the VM my service runs in (Java settings, Tomcat, Rabbit settings..)

The service doesn't do anything explicit with connections or ack policies, so it's possible they may need to be tweaked?
A few articles mention that there should be one channel per consumer (or even 1 for consume and 1 for publish), but that makes things slower than the larger figure above..

I'm at a loss, so any help is appreciated, more details can be provided.

Java: 7
Spring Core: 3.2.2
Rabbit AMQP: 3.1.2
Spring Rabbit: 1.3.5
Spring AMQP: 1.3.5

EDIT: I'm using a ConnectionFactory in Spring XML config (defaults to a CachingConnectionFactory I believe) that I set the channel cache size on, and then set the factory into the listener container, dunno if that helps..

Comment: What is "channel cache size". Is that something from your library? That is definitely not a setting from RabbitMQ AFAIK. Also do you have a multi core machine for RabbitMQ?

Comment: Channel cache size is a setting on the connectionFactory that is configured in Spring.     <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                               host="${rabbit.host}"
                               port="${rabbit.port}"
                               username="${rabbit.username}"
                               password="${rabbit.password}"
                               channel-cache-size="${rabbit.cache.size}"
                               connection-factory="sslEnabledConnectionFactory"/>

Answer (score 2):

I'm leaning towards it being an issue with the number of channels and the channel cache size. Does anyone know if there's a limit on the number of channels on a queue?

It seems like specifying connections rather than channels might help here.

If anyone has any information it would really help,  getting stuck for time :)